# 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials in Adobe Experience Manager

Tags: aem

Cant to login in AEM in Firefox and chrome browsers.Its showing 401 error.
   "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials".

But successfully logged-in IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SSO?

If you are, then check that your SSO headers are appropriately attached when the browser makes the request:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/single-sign-on.html

If you are not using SSO, have you customized your login stack? If you have, then check to make sure that your login-token header is appropriate:

For me:

(Chrome)

Cookie:login-token=07a20328-7af3-41f5-806f-54295e2c453f%3ac4594cd8-0bdc-49f9-ad54-0f655a4d64fd_4a3c4e90439dec5c%3acrx.default; cq-authoring-mode=TOUCH; cq-projects=card

(Safari)

login-token 07a20328-7af3-41f5-806f-54295e2c453f%3af8f459d3-6acc-4bde-9a3c-28d3281fc33e_e6ce38d3ed6a2d81%3acrx.default  localhost   /   Session 117 B   ✓

Note, the first part *should* be similar for both browsers if you are logging in as the same user on the same stack.

Check inside crxde for the login tokens by performing a search for the token string, and check to make sure that the tokens are being generated for both browsers.

Comment: Yes we are using SSO...Only in FireFox browser we facing this login issues.

Comment: Are you using SPNEGO or SAML?